# Change color of Applet context menu font or background

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, icons, fonts

As seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAhqO.png, theres little contrast between the greys.

I'm using the FlatStudio theme with Faenza Dark icons. I'm assuming it's because the icons are for a dark theme, thus using a light font color.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix so I thought I'd share it here in case someone stumbles upon this with the same issue.

I installed `gtk-theme-config` and changed the options under "Custom menu colors" to:

- Menu background: dark grey
- Meun text: white

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt7Ak.jpg

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```